# Debugging Dynamically Allocated 2D Array with Xcode 5

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, xcode5

I've the following C code that creates a dynamically allocated 2D array.

```
numbersArray = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)* primeNumber);

for (i =0 ; i < primeNumber; i++)
    numbersArray[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
```

`numbersArray` is globally defined and primeNumber is just a number that I calculate during the execution of the program.

My program performs well without problems. I can do various processes on the array. It works totally fine.

My question is that Xcode 5 doesn't show the contents of `numbersArray` when debugging. It just shows the following:

[image: Debug area in Xcode 5]

Why can't it display the dynamically allocated array properly that I would be able to see each and every cell in the array?

I checked similar questions before posting this and they talked about dynamic allocation that the compiler isn't aware of the array size(s) until runtime but I think I remember that before(in previous versions of Xcode) I was able to see the contents of a dynamically allocated array.

What's really going on here? Has it been always like this or is it an Xcode 5 thing or maybe I have the configure Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Now, I think you mis-remember. Unless it's doing pretty advanced analysis, there should be no way for the debugger to know that an `int **` variable should be interpreted as an array of a specific size.

What you can often do, is use various "view memory as ..."-type commands to inspect the memory. This will be even more complicated by the fact that your array is "jagged", i.e. each row is a pointer to that rows's data rather than the entire array being a single contiguous allocation.

Comment: OP could check the return value of malloc too.

Comment: Yeap, guess I misremember. Thanks for the tip. Also could you please share some commands to inspect the memory. Like how can I inspect a double array?